# Axios patch with an array of integers as a parameter

Tags: javascript, axios

I need to send a patch to an endpoint with some parameters.
One of those parameters is an array of integers.

This is the log of my parameter object right before passing it to the call: https://gyazo.com/0a9042dc2411d9f25cc52080cc3b90c9

The problem is that the array is being converted to a float: https://gyazo.com/4172379c0ab607a9b1abb4e87fe867db

Is this some kind of issue from axios?

```
  let params = {}
  params.description = ""
  params.files = [400, 401]
  console.log("Params: " , params)
  try {
    yield call(axios.patch, endpoint, params)
  } catch (er) {
    console.log(er)
    if (er.response.data) {
      // map WS return errors to form format
      // put the errors on each field and changed them to invalid
      const newForm = mapWSErrorsToForm(er.response.data, form)
      yield put(changeForm(newForm))
      // try to scroll to first form field error
      scrollToFirstFormError(newForm)
    }
    yield put(error([]))
  }
```

Comment: Do you try to stringify you array ?

Comment: The API is expecting a list (an array) instead of a string. If i stringify the array it wil throw an exception.